# How to access the validation for single field in EditForm?

Tags: blazor, blazor-client-side, blazor-webassembly, asp.net-blazor

I want to manipulate css based on validation results in an `<EditForm />`.

My simplified form looks like this

```
<EditForm Model="Registration" OnValidSubmit="Submit">
    <label for="input-username">Username</label>
    <InputText id="input-username" 
               type="text" 
               class="???" 
               @bind-Value="Registration.Username" />
    <p>
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => Registration.Username)" />
    </p>
</EditForm>
```

My form hast more fields than this one so I want to filter the validations only for `Registration.Username` to only edit the css-class for `#input-username`.

Answer (score 2):

You can subscribe to the OnFieldChanged event of the EditContext object, find out which field has changed and act accordingly.

```
<EditForm EditContext="EditContext" OnValidSubmit="Submit">
    <DataAnnotationsValidator />

     <label for="input-username">Username</label>
    <InputText id="input-username" type="text" class="MyUsername" 
               @bind-Value="Registration.Username" />
    <p>
        <ValidationMessage For="@(() => Registration.Username)" />
    </p>
            <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        
</EditForm>

@code
{
    private Registration Model = new Registration();
    private EditContext EditContext;
    private string MyUsername = "InitialCssClass";

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        EditContext = new EditContext(Model);

        EditContext.OnFieldChanged += EditContext_OnFieldChanged;

    }

    private void EditContext_OnFieldChanged(object sender, 
                                         FieldChangedEventArgs e)
    {
         if (e.FieldIdentifier.FieldName == nameof(Model.Username))
         {
             MyUsername = "Set here a new class name, etc.";
         }
    }
}
```